# Keychain Access Oddness?

Tags: ios, certificate, keychain

In my Keychain Access I have my distribution certificates and there is an odd bug where if I delete a certain certificate, it comes back after I close the application or if I restart Xcode. This certificate is my second distribution certificate and I do not use it for anything but whenever I try to archive something it says:

> (My Name) distribution certificate appears more than once in the
>   keychain.

So I delete it and everything is fine because I didn't restart anything. But once I do, it comes back even though I delete it!

Is this a bug or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a bug with the Keychain application. I am having the same problem but with other Keychain items. I delete them but as soon as I interact with an application that uses the Keychain, such as a web browser visiting a page with a remembered password, all of the removed items comes back. It doesn't matter if I restart the computer after the deletion, the items still comes back.

I've had the very same thing happening in Safari where cookies keep coming back. Both on OS X Snow Leopard and Lion. Very frustrating and worrying.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Unfortunately this doesn't answer my question so I'm not going to accept it but I did up vote it :) Let me know if you manage to fix it.

Comment: Ok, so I've identified what was causing the strange behavior on my computer where keychain passwords where re-appearing in the keychain. It turned out Google Chrome was to blame. When I removed the passwords from Keychain and Google Chrome they stopped re-appearing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally managed to solve it: I had to remove the certificate from the cache xCode keeps. Then every time I would load xCode it would re-add the old certificate and then complain that I have two of the same (smart xCode!).

Solution:
*Delete certificate from keychain.
*ALSO delete everything related to it in xCode Organizer (command+shift+2).

To be sure I quit both key-chain and xcode, re-start them and it is finally gone.